# Use result from observable as property

Tags: angular

I have the following service that is used throughout my app

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class UserSettingsService {
    private url = "urlToUserSettings"
    private gebruikersettings: UserSettings;

    constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
    }

    GetUserSettings(): Observable<UserSettings> {
        return this.client.get<UserSettings>(this.url);
    }
}
```

The services that require the UserSettings need to implements this by subscribing first to the GetUserSettings and then they need to perform their own get method creating something as following

```
GetSomeData(): Observable<SomeData>{
    return this.userSettingsService.GetUserSettings()
        .pipe(flatMap(result => {
            return this.http.get<SomeData>(`${url}/${result.userCode}`)
                .pipe(map(result => result["SomeData"]));
        }));
}
```

As the application gets more complex this gets more repeated so my question is if it is possible to put the results of GetUserSettings() as a property in UserSettingsService and just use that property as following

```
GetSomeData(): Observable<SomeData>{
    return this.http.get<SomeData>(`${url}/${userSettingsService.property.userCode}`)
        .pipe(map(result => result["SomeData"]));
}
```

Comment: If it's a user settings store it in local storage/session?

Comment: I think that still creates the problem with some components that require the UserSettings on ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

why don't you subscribe to the observable and simply use the result of service method?
you should do something like this:

```
enter code hereGetSomeData(): Observable<SomeData>{
    this.userSettingsService.GetUserSettings().subscribe(result => {
        return this.http.get<SomeData>(`${url}/result`)
        .pipe(map(result => result["SomeData"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return an observable.